# Какая файловая система лучше восстанавливается после "случайного" форматирования?

Tags: файловая-система, ос, ntfs, ext4

Всегда слышал, да и читал что надо делать бекапы ежесекундно. Но про все что там писалось и говорилось обычно обходило меня стороной. И вот недавно при записи образа на внешний хард я случайно не доглядев начал записывать его на свой личный винт. И собственно вот сижу уже непойми какой день восстанавливаю все что могу восстановить. И стало интересно, может есть какая то статистика по восстановлениям данных, и какая файловая система лучше всего восстанавливает данные.

Comment: если Вы переписываете поверху, то тут все равно, какая была файловая система

Comment: обычно `raid-1` (зеркальный) массив помогает. Чуть-что и делаете восстановление. А в `ntfs` наверное только через RAID-1 в биосе.

Comment: сильно сомневаюсь, что рейд поможет.

Comment: не уверен но ZFS-ка кажется много чего интересного умеет, например если случайно форматнул диск на котором ZFS можно достаточно быстро(тут я не уверен) восстановить через zpool import